# Ansible win_msi installation fails

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, winrm

I'm trying to make this work for a while now, running out of ideas.

I got an .msi file which I want to install on a Win7 client using Ansible.
The playbook runs through but in the end the program won't be installed.

I also cannot make it work with the "raw" command which works with .exe files but doesn't seem to work with my .msi file.

Specs:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.2.0.0
```

OS i'm trying to install on is Win7 Proffesional.

Powershell version is:

```
$psversiontable

Name         Value
----         -----
PSVersion    5.0.10589.117
```

Playbook looks like this:

```
 - name: Install zarafaclient version 7.2
     win_msi:
       path: 'C:\\temp_files\\z7.2.msi'
       state: present
```

I also tried different syntaxes, so the playbook shouldn't be the issue.

Here is what I get from ansible if I run it with -vvvv

```
TASK [Install zarafaclient version 7.2] ****************************************
task path: /home/pfl/ansible/Provisioning-Windows-with-Ansible/playbook.yml:10
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/core/windows/win_msi.ps1
<192.168.37.144> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: fdsadm on PORT 5986 TO 192.168.37.144
<192.168.37.144> EXEC Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
(New-Item -Type Directory -Path $env:temp -Name "ansible-tmp-1481285937.55-262476455300775").FullName | Write-Host -Separator '';
<192.168.37.144> PUT "/tmp/tmp0l4Ayh" TO "C:\Users\fdsadm\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1481285937.55-262476455300775\win_msi.ps1"
<192.168.37.144> EXEC Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
Try
{
& 'C:\Users\fdsadm\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1481285937.55-262476455300775\win_msi.ps1'
}
Catch
{
$_obj = @{ failed = $true }
If ($_.Exception.GetType)
{
$_obj.Add('msg', $_.Exception.Message)
}
Else
{
$_obj.Add('msg', $_.ToString())
}
If ($_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)
{
$_obj.Add('exception', $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage)
}
ElseIf ($_.ScriptStackTrace)
{
$_obj.Add('exception', $_.ScriptStackTrace)
}
Try
{
$_obj.Add('error_record', ($_ | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json))
}
Catch
{
}
Echo $_obj | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 99
Exit 1
}
Finally { Remove-Item "C:\Users\fdsadm\AppData\Local\Temp\ansible-tmp-1481285937.55-262476455300775" -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
changed: [192.168.37.144] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "win_msi"
    }, 
    "log": ""
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.37.144             : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like an issue with the spacing

I think it you should look like

```
- name: Install zarafaclient version 7.2
  win_msi:
    path: 'C:\\temp_files\\z7.2.msi'
    state: present
```